# Laptop won't boot in the morning only

Tags: boot

My Dell vostro 2520 won't boot in the morning  it is installed with Ubuntu and Ubuntu shows read error and if I try repeatedly to switch on it will boot after many tries and after that for the whole  day it would show no problem but in the next morning when I power on the laptop it would not boot and if I try it will boot after some time .I need to know what is the problem why it is difficult to boot only in the morning.Is it related to hardisk or  sata port.hardisk is always detected in the bios but when I perform diagnosis it shows hardrive problem.but the system can boot without any problem for the whole day if it booted in the morning.but it takes many tries to boot correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your harddisk has bad sectors preventing it from functioning correctly. Try to run a full disk check or maybe a full format will do.

Comment: I checked the whole hardisk using surface testing and it shows no problem with any of the sectors and today when I power on the laptop it won't boot and even the hdd is not detected in the bios.but after half hour of repeatedly rebooting it boots correctly.is this problem related to motherboard or hdd that is contraction of something when leaving laptop for long time unused.